# Traverse decision tree based on values; iteratively going into sub-dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, tree, decision-tree, tree-traversal

I have a dictionary which represents a decision tree:

```py
{'Outlook': {'Overcast': 'Yes', 'Rain': {'Wind': {'Strong': 'No', 'Weak': 'Yes'}}, 'Sunny': {'Temperature': {'Cool': 'Yes', 'Hot': 'No', 'Mild': 'No'}}}}
```

Visualized, it looks like below:

[image]

This tree was made with some training data and an ID3 algorithm; I wish to predict the decision for examples from my testing data:

```
Outlook   Temperature Humidity Wind    Decision
Sunny     Mild        Normal   Strong  Yes
Overcast  Mild        High     Strong  Yes
Overcast  Hot         Normal   Weak    Yes
Rain      Mild        High     Strong  No
```

Using the first example, a rough idea of the order things are checked:

```
Current dict 'outlook'
Examine 'outlook', found 'sunny':
  'sunny' is a dict, make current dict the 'sunny' subdict
  Examine 'temperature', found 'mild':
     'mild' is not a dict, return value 'no'
```

I'm not sure how to traverse the dictionary like this, however. I've got some code to start with:

```py
def fun(d, t):
    """
    d -- decision tree dictionary
    t -- testing examples in form of pandas dataframe
    """
    for _, e in t.iterrows():
        predict(d, e)

def predict(d, e):
    """
    d -- decision tree dictionary
    e -- a testing example in form of pandas series
    """
    # ?
```

In `predict()`, `e` can be accessed as a dictionary:

```py
print(e.to_dict())
# {'Outlook': 'Rain', 'Temperature': 'Cool', 'Humidity': 'Normal', 'Wind': 'Weak', 'Decision': 'Yes'}
print(e['Outlook'])
# 'Rain'
print(e['Decision'])
# 'Yes'
# etc
```

I'm just not sure how to traverse the dict. I need to iterate over the testing example in the order attributes appear in the decision tree, not in the order they appear in the testing example.

Comment: Can you post an example of `e` testing example?

Comment: @Poojan `e` can be accessed as a dictionary itself.

Comment: dict's aren't great for preserving order in many versions of python.  Is there anything wrong with using recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to implement recursive solution to search until you reach a node with string value (that will be your leaf node with decision "Yes" or "No").

```py
import pandas as pd

dt = {'Outlook': {'Overcast': 'Yes', 'Rain': {'Wind': {'Strong': 'No', 'Weak': 'Yes'}}, 'Sunny': {'Temperature': {'Cool': 'Yes', 'Hot': 'No', 'Mild': 'No'}}}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Sunny', 'Mild', 'Normal', 'Strong', 'Yes']],columns=['Outlook', 'Temperature', 'Humidity', 'Wind', 'Decision'])

def fun(d, t):
    """
    d -- decision tree dictionary
    t -- testing examples in form of pandas dataframe
    """
    res = []
    for _, e in t.iterrows():
        res.append(predict(d, e))
    return res

def predict(d, e):
    """
    d -- decision tree dictionary
    e -- a testing example in form of pandas series
    """
    current_node = list(d.keys())[0]
    current_branch = d[current_node][e[current_node]]
    # if leaf node value is string then its a decision
    if isinstance(current_branch, str):
        return current_branch
    # else use that node as new searching subtree
    else:
        return predict(current_branch, e)

print(fun(dt, df))
```

output:

> ['No']

Comment: Did you mean `fun(dt, df)` otherwise it assumes a single row in the test data (and you wouldn't use `.item()` in `predict()`).

Comment: Adding to what @AChampion said, instead performing `fun(dt, df)` yields error `Attribute error: 'str' object has no attribute 'item'`.

Comment: @AChampion Thanks for noticing the bug.

Comment: Just a question: on some runs using a larger data set, I get things like `KeyError: '...'` traced to line `current_branch = d[current_node][e[current_node]]`. Consider a new example like `['Sunny', 'Cold', 'Normal', 'Strong', 'Yes']`: `Cold` does not appear as a value for `Temperature` but may exist in the testing data. This is a consequence of ID3 not being perfect. Any ideas?

Comment: @gator Yes there might be data that you do not have in training. Or the data is not used in training. Since you do not have in training data you definitely cant predict for that data. I suggest you look for this cases. And try to add more data into decision tree is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can also implement this iteratively just keeping track of the current dict:

```
def predict(d, e):
    """
    d -- decision tree dictionary
    e -- a testing example in form of pandas series
    """
    c = d
    for k, v in e.iteritems():
        print(f"Current dict '{k}'")
        try:
            c = c[k][v]
        except KeyError:
            # Do something sensible here
            continue
        print(f"Examine '{k}', found '{v}': ")
        if isinstance(c, dict):
            print(f"'{v}' is a dict, make current dict the '{v}' subdict")
        else:
            print(f"'{v}' is not a dict, return {c}\n")
            return c

fun(data, test)
```

Results in:

```
Current dict 'Outlook'
Examine 'Outlook', found 'Sunny': 
'Sunny' is a dict, make current dict the 'Sunny' subdict
Current dict 'Temperature'
Examine 'Temperature', found 'Mild': 
'Mild' is not a dict, return No

Current dict 'Outlook'
Examine 'Outlook', found 'Overcast': 
'Overcast' is not a dict, return Yes

Current dict 'Outlook'
Examine 'Outlook', found 'Overcast': 
'Overcast' is not a dict, return Yes

Current dict 'Outlook'
Examine 'Outlook', found 'Rain': 
'Rain' is a dict, make current dict the 'Rain' subdict
Current dict 'Temperature'
Current dict 'Humidity'
Current dict 'Wind'
Examine 'Wind', found 'Strong': 
'Strong' is not a dict, return No
```